# Sql Server large data

Tags: performance, database-performance, query-performance, large-data-volumes

- I have **sql server 2012** installed on a Virtual machine.
- With **quad core processor (2.0 GHz) and 32 GB RAM.**
- The Data volume is about **400 GB** and there is a `Table with 824 million records`
  in it.
- The Records are **date wise**.
- I have to pull data from this table as per the `start date and end date given by the user`. - this generally takes **24 minutes** to process query.
- Is there is any way to **optimize** this ,
- even I have tried **sql server 2012 column store index** in it yet there is no significant improvement in the performance of the query.
- Should i ask for some higher machine configurations for such large data or is there is any other way to achieve good performance in it?

Comment: Do you have indices on the start_date and end_date fields? Are these simple dates, or timestamps?

Comment: If it takes 24 minutes you're probably doing something wrong. More details would be nice.